# How to X11 forwarding through ssh in 15.10

Tags: 15.10, x11-forwarding

Since I am on Ubuntu, I'll try to have X11 forwarding through ssh on a remote desktop. But unfortunately it does not work.
Before I do this :

```
ssh -X username@hostname
```

and then for example :

```
gedit
```

But now under Ubuntu 15.10 It does not work and I have this message :

```
$ gedit Failed to connect to **Mir**: Failed to connect to server socket: No files or folders of this type Unable to init server: Unable to connect: Connection refused

(gedit:2492): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

So my question is how to have X11 forwarding through ssh ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable X-Forwarding in the SSH server configuration, in 
`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

It should look like:

```
X11Forwarding Yes
```

Uncomment any comments before this line.

After restarting the SSH Server everything should works fine.

Comment: I have already configure my /etc/ssh/sshd_config but it does not work. I still ahve the same error with Mir. I use X11 forwarding for a while but under 15.04 and 15.10 it does not work

Comment: In fact it's a bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1463263